# Error while evaluating new data on weka java API

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, weka

When i am trying to evaluate a new testing data on already trained classifier it brings me null point exception.

Here is the code

```
String[] optionsj = new String[2];

optionsj[0] = "-C";
optionsj[1] = "0.25";

// a decision tree
//Training
Classifier cls = new J48();
cls.setOptions(optionsj);
Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(data);
Random rand = new Random(1);  // using seed = 1
int folds = 10;
eval.crossValidateModel(cls, data, folds, rand);
System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString());     

System.out.println(eval.toClassDetailsString());

//Testing

Evaluation evaltest = new Evaluation(data);
evaltest.evaluateModel(cls, data2);  // line 193
System.out.println(evaltest.toSummaryString());

//data and data2 are two instances of same dataset.
```

Error i am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat 
at weka.classifiers.trees.J48.distributionForInstance(Unknown Source)
at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(Unknown Source)
at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Unknown Source)
at dentis.Simplified.main(Simplified.java:193)
```

I cant print the dataset out without a problem. What is this problem? why it occur and how to fix it?

Comment: Is the line that is crashing at line 193 the evaluateModel call?  Also, it seems strange that J48 is referenced in your stack trace when you are using an MLP.

Comment: opz sorry i was using MLPNet various classifiers and i post the wrong code segmant. done corrected it

Comment: Did you just type your stack trace?  There's something about 'multilayerpocepton' that doesn't seem quite right. Perhaps copy the actual stack trace message please :)

Comment: Sorry about earlier. fix the entire problem with original code and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are using evaluateModel you need to build the classifier on the training set first.

```
cls.buildClassifier(data);
```

Comment: yes... i figured that out at the morning .Thanks a lot for the reply